# How to use MultiBinding many times, in abbreviated form, each with different ConverterParameter?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, multibinding, xaml-binding

I have a `IMultiValueConverter` called `Placer`, being use like this:

```
<Rectangle Name="HostBox" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="36" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="32" 
            Width="86" RadiusY="9.5" RadiusX="9.5">
    <Canvas.Left>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Placer}" ConverterParameter="0.5">
            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}"/>
            <Binding Path="Width" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Canvas.Left>
</Rectangle>
```

But I have many `Rectangle`s, on which I want to apply the same logic, but with different `ConverterParameter` value. Do I have to include this not-so-small snippet under each `Rectangle`'s `Canvas.Left` attached property? (rhetorical question... obviously there's a smarter way... but how?)

Comment: Just a thought, but it might perhaps be much easier to implement a [custom panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx#Panels_custom_panel_elements) with special layout behaviour, as for example shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21158560/1136211).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a style. For instance, the following one is applied to all the rectangle instances but you could also give it a key and apply it individually to your rectangles:

```
    <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Placer}" ConverterParameter="0.5">
                    <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}"/>
                    <Binding Path="Width" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

<strike>In order to parameterize `MultiBinding.ConverterParameter` you may simply use a binding.</strike>

EDIT: I stand corrected about binding to `MultiBinding.ConverterParameter`: it is not possible since it is not a `DependencyProperty` but [you can work around it.](http://www.shujaat.net/2011/02/wpf-binding-converter-parameter.html)

Comment: But then I cannot change the `ConverterParameter`

Comment: How do I parameterize `MultiBinding.ConverterParameter` that's inside a `Style`, using binding in the target `Rectangle`?

Comment: Once the style is applied to an element, the bindings apply to that element's `DataContext`. Thus, you can bind to an appropriate View Model property.

Comment: Doesn't feel right to mix pure appearance (`View`), with `viewModel`

Comment: I just assumed you had some logic behind that parameter value in your View Model. Of course, you may bind it to anything within your logic tree..