# Display ListViewItems as Circles

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

What's the best way to display items in a listview as circles?
I want to embed the name of the item within the circle.

Do I use a ItemContainerStyle?

I assume I use a controltemplate. However, I'm confused as I consider its relationship with the ItemContainerStyle.

What's wrong with the following code?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}" 
          CanDragItems="True" DragItemsStarting="OnDragItemStarting">
    <ListViewItem  Style="{StaticResource ContactsListItemStyle}"  />
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding DisplayName}">
                    <ContentControl.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <ContentControl>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Ellipse Fill="LightGray" Height="50" Width="50" />
                                    <Viewbox>
                                        <ContentControl Margin="20" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                                    </Viewbox>
                                </Grid>
                            </ContentControl>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ContentControl.Template>
                </ContentControl>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: You have to set `ItemTemplate` of `ListView`.

Comment: Is there an example you can point me to?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22325266/1136211) should be helpful. Replace Rectangles by Ellipses (or Paths with EllipseGeometries).

Comment: Do you mean you want the LIST to display in a circular layout?  Or each individual ITEM within the list to be displayed in a circle of sorts?  If the entire list to be in a circle, you need to create a new ItemsPanel on your own.  If the latter, this would be a part of your ItemTemplate as mentioned

Comment: I want each individual item within the list to be displayed as a circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XAML works:

```
<Page.Resources>
       <ControlTemplate x:Key="ContentControlTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
            <ContentControl>
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Fill="LightGray" Height="200" Width="200" />
                    <Viewbox>
                        <ContentControl Margin="20" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </Viewbox>
                </Grid>
            </ContentControl>
        </ControlTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}" 
                  CanDragItems="True" DragItemsStarting="OnDragItemStarting">
            <ListViewItem  Style="{StaticResource ContactsListItemStyle}"  />
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource ContentControlTemplate}" 
                                        Content="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```