# WPF. How do I create several child controls via data-binding?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have UserControl that includes several rectangles:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Rectangle Height="70" Width="100" x:Name="Image1" />
    <Rectangle Height="70" Width="100" x:Name="Image2" />
    <Rectangle Height="70" Width="100" x:Name="Image3" />
</StackPanel>
```

How can I create various number of rectangles via data binding and set rectangles width and height (and other properties) instead of this static hardcode approach?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: See e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22325266/1136211) for some more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you would have an `ItemsControl` (or a `ListBox`, etc.) and modify its item template to show the rectangles:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding MyRectangles}>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Note that this assumes the data context has a `MyRectangles` collection, and each item within that collection has a `Width` and `Height` property.