# WPF C# | Delete rectangle within canvas by coordinates

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, rectangles

I have 2 canvas components and I want these to be synchronized at all times. Once i add a rectangle to canvas 1, I also add it to canvas 2.
I remove the rectangle within canvas 1 in the following way:

```
Rectangle rec = Mouse.DirectlyOver as Rectangle;
if (rec != null)
{
       drawCanvas.Children.Remove(rec);
       drawCanvas.UpdateLayout();
}
```

How would i delete the rectangle at the same position within canvas 2?

Comment: Couldn't you just bind both canvas to the same source?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22325266/1136211) about how to add Rectangles to a Canvas in an MVVM manner. Then bind two such ItemsControls to the same view model.

Comment: I have used an observablecollection and have done exactly that, thx guys ;)