# WPF - C# - Creating and setting image coordinates in code - behind

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, artificial-intelligence, path-finding

I currently work on WPF application according to my AI interest.
I wrote a Uniform Cost Search algorithm (pathfinding) and want to present it in graphical way.
Path should be found and show on a graph which could be adjusted by user.

I'm quite new in WPF technology, I worked more with WinForms and now have a problem with creating and managing graphical elements.

In other words - I want to give opportunity to click on data grid and create your own node (sth like place on a map) which is represented by a picture, when you have a few nodes you can choose two of them and connect them to make a connection, finally you can select your start and end point and algorithm will show the shortest path (color the suitable connections).

That's it.

[Image with interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpvxq.png)

I started with adding a CreateNode method which gets click's coordinates and create a point with right X and Y. Now there is a problem with creating an image in that specific place.

I read some questions on Stack and tried to write something with Image and BitmapImge classes but still don't know how to place it in specific place.
I read about manipulating margins but aren't there any easier solutions?

Here's part of that image loading code:

```
        public void CreateNode(Node n)
        {
        Point point = new Point(n.X, n.Y);

        Image node = new Image();
        BitmapImage logo = new BitmapImage();
        logo.BeginInit();
        logo.UriSource = new Uri("point.png");
        logo.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        logo.EndInit();

        node.Source = logo;
        }
```

If someone has any ideas how to create these methods in case of graphics I will really aprreciate that.

Thanks in advance

Paweł

EDIT: I was said to create new topic for my code problem so here is that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208637/c-sharp-wpf-connecting-code-behind-with-xaml-elements)

Comment: With the positioning, I'd recommend watching [this video on advanced XAML techniques](https://youtu.be/Wb-l0e6WYE0?t=3228). He uses a custom `ItemsControl` and `Canvas` to bind the longitude and latitude of delivery trucks to show as graphics on a map. I think some of his techniques could work in your situation (or give you further ideas). I've linked to the a timestamp at the start of the relevant section.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22325266/1136211) and in the DataTemplate replace `<Rectangle .../>` by `<Image Source="point.png"/>`.

Comment: Thank you both guys, I'll try to write something with ItemsControl and Canvas. I'm not sure whether I have enough knowledge so it would be nice if you can follow that question in case I would fail.

Comment: It would probably be better to post new questions for issues you get stuck with. Just make sure to include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the new question. More people will see it and potentially have an answer on a new question, and a few other reasons listed in [How to Ask a question which is a continuation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204139/how-to-ask-a-question-which-is-a-continuation/204141#204141).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer to provide a little more information.

With the positioning, I'd recommend watching this video on [advanced XAML techniques](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wb-l0e6WYE0&feature=youtu.be&t=3228). He uses a custom ItemsControl and Canvas to bind the longitude and latitude of delivery trucks to show as graphics on a map. I think some of his techniques could work in your situation (or give you further ideas). I've linked to the a timestamp at the start of the relevant section.

The source code for the relevant demo is [available here](https://xaml.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Events/2014%20TechEd%20Europe/DEV-B311%20XAML%20Techniques/Demo05/). See Events - 2014 TechEd Europe - DEV-B311 XAML Techniques - Demo05

The main difference from what you're doing to the video is that he uses `Paths` where you want to use images. You'd need to change the `DataTemplates` in App.xaml.cs to use images.

The video assumes some knowledge of MVVM, so if that's new to you, it's probably worth checking out a tutorial. You can find some recommendations [in the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish/2034333#2034333). I'd also recommend one on [Rachel Lim's Blog](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/). I found her tutorials very useful.

The [first linked tutorials](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/a-guided-tour-of-wpf/) on WPF look like they will be useful to you. In addition to the basics it includes using images in `DataTemplates`.