# Add Shape information to a ListView when its created

Tags: c#, wpf

Im creating shapes(rectangles, ellipse, line) in to a canvas. And then i have in another window a listview where i need to input the information of the shape(such like position, size, what shape it is).

I have this code in XAML in another window:

```
    <ListView Name="Information">

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Type"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="PositionX"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="PositionY"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Width" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ActualWidth}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Height" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ActualHeight}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>

    </ListView>
```

and in c# of the main window, i have an observable collection and this code:

```
ObservableCollection<Shape> shapes = new ObservableCollection<Shape>();

myRect.Width = var1;
myRect.Height = var2;
Page.Children.Add(myRect);
Canvas.SetLeft(myRect, posx);
Canvas.SetTop(myRect, posy);

shapes.Add(myRect);
2ndwindow.Information.ItemsSource = shapes; // this is working because the 2ndwindow is owned by the mainwindow
```

EDIT: i managed to bind the width and height, but i dont know how to bind the position and the shape it is(rectangle or ellipse)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22325266/1136211) for an explanation about how to do this with Rectangles in an MVVM application. You could generalize it by declaring different shape types (classes) and use different DataTemplates for them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a proper MVVM approach, you should have a view model with an abstract representation of a Shape (instead of a list of UI elements), e.g. like this:

```
public class ShapeData
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Geometry Geometry { get; set; }
    public Brush Fill { get; set; }
    public Brush Stroke { get; set; }
    public double StrokeThickness { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ShapeData> Shapes { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<ShapeData>();
}
```

You could now bind this view model to a view like shown below. The position and size of each shape is retrieved from the `Bounds` property of the `Geometry` of a shape object.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Shapes}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Path Data="{Binding Geometry}"
                      Fill="{Binding Fill}"
                      Stroke="{Binding Stroke}"
                      StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

    <ListView Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Shapes}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Type"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="X"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Geometry.Bounds.X}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Y"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Geometry.Bounds.Y}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Width" 
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Geometry.Bounds.Width}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Height"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Geometry.Bounds.Height}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

You could create a view model instance in your window's constructor and add some sample data like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var viewModel = new ViewModel();

    viewModel.Shapes.Add(new ShapeData
    {
        Type = "Circle",
        Geometry = new EllipseGeometry(new Point(100, 100), 50, 50),
        Fill = Brushes.Orange,
        Stroke = Brushes.Navy,
        StrokeThickness = 2
    });

    viewModel.Shapes.Add(new ShapeData
    {
        Type = "Rectangle",
        Geometry = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(200, 50, 50, 100)),
        Fill = Brushes.Yellow,
        Stroke = Brushes.DarkGreen,
        StrokeThickness = 2
    });

    DataContext = viewModel;
}
```