# Make attached properties work inside DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, attached-properties

I got an `ItemsControl` which uses a `Canvas` as `ItemsPanel` and its items are rendered to different WPF shapes depending on the bound type, basically like this:

```
<ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding PreviewShapes}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UiPreviewLineViewModel}">
            <Line X1="{Binding Start.X}" Y1="{Binding Start.Y}"
                        X2="{Binding End.X}" Y2="{Binding End.Y}" 
                        StrokeThickness="0.75" Stroke="{Binding Brush}" x:Name="Line" ToolTip="{Binding Text}">
            </Line>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UiPreviewEllipsisViewModel}">
            <Ellipse Canvas.Left="{Binding UpperLeft.X" Canvas.Top="{Binding UpperLeft.Y}" 
                     Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" 
                     StrokeThickness="0.75" Stroke="{Binding Brush}" x:Name="Ellipse" ToolTip="{Binding Text}">
            </Ellipse>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="SketchCanvas" ClipToBounds="False">
            </Canvas>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

So I basically add objects to `PreviewShapes` of the viewmodel and depending on the type they are rendered to WPF `Line`s or `Ellipse`s. That basically works but the attached properties `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` are ignored, even when using static values.

Also VS or ReSharper notifies me that the attached property has no effect in the current context.

How can I position the `Ellipse` on the canvas without using the attached properties? Or what other solution would be appropiate?

Comment: The elements in the DataTemplate won't become direct children of the Canvas (because they will be used as Content of a ContentPresenter that serves as item container). You can only set `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` in an ItemContainerStyle, as shown e.g. in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22325266/1136211). [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40190793/1136211) may also be helpful.

Comment: Besides that, having a ListBoxItem Style in the Resources of an ItemsControl looks odd.

Comment: That `Style` must be a relict from older code, I remove it from the sample code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately nobody felt like posting an answer.

First, Clemens links are helpful. The items will be inside a `ContentPresenter` which is the reason why setting `Canvas.Left/Top` on the `Ellipsis` does not work.

**Solution 1**

By adding a style to the item container the bindings for the position can be set there:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding UpperLeft.X}" />
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding UpperLeft.Y}" />
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

This works but the `DataTemplate` placing `<Line>` will produce binding warnings because that view model does not have a property `UpperLeft`. Nevertheless it works for the ellipsis and the lines are placed by their `X1`, `Y1`, `X2` and `Y2` values.

**Solution 2**

If you would like to use a more fine grained control approach you can set the attached `Canvas` properties to the `ContentPresenter` by proxing them with a custom behaviour / attached property. Let's name it *CanvasPointProxyBehavior*, you could use it for the `Ellipse` like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UiPreviewEllipsisViewModel}">
    <Ellipse behaviors:CanvasPointProxyBehavior.Point="{Binding UpperLeft}"
             Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" 
             StrokeThickness="0.75" Stroke="{Binding Brush}" x:Name="Ellipse" ToolTip="{Binding Text}">
    </Ellipse>
</DataTemplate>
```

The `Line` will not need it. The code for this attached property might look like this:

```
public class CanvasPointProxyBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PointProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Point", typeof(Point), typeof(CanvasPointProxyBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, PointChangedCallback));

    public static void SetPoint(DependencyObject depObj, Point point)
    {
        depObj.SetValue(PointProperty, point);
    }

    public static Point GetPoint(DependencyObject depObj)
    {
        return depObj.GetValue(PointProperty) as Point;
    }

    private static void PointChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement uiElement = (dependencyObject as UIElement);
        if (uiElement == null) return;
        UIElement elementToBePositioned = uiElement;
        var visualParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(uiElement);
        if (visualParent is ContentPresenter)
        {
            elementToBePositioned = visualParent as ContentPresenter;
        }

        var point = e.NewValue as Point;
        if (point != null)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(elementToBePositioned, point.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(elementToBePositioned, point.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Hoping someone will find one or both solution useful.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I encountered the same ReSharper warning message as [@ZoolWay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/573870/zoolway), but in my case it was within a data grid, where I wanted the button on the right to be right-aligned instead of left-aligned:

> Attached property setting "Grid.Column" has no effect in current
>   context and can be removed.

Here is the code where I had the warning, on the `Button Grid.Column="2"`:

```
        <Border VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource InspectionsCustomDataGridHeader}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Label Name="InspectionsDataGridTitle" Background="White" Content="{Binding InspectionsCollectionView.View.Count, ConverterParameter={x:Static resx:Resources.InspectionsDataGridTitle}, Converter={StaticResource DataGridHeaderCountConverter}}" Style="{DynamicResource InspectionsCustomDataGridHeaderLabel}" MouseDown="InspectionsDataGridTitle_MouseDown" />
                    <!-- more labels, etc... -->
                    <Button Grid.Column="2" Width="30" Height="30" Margin="0,0,10,0" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Command="{Binding CreatePDFCommand,Mode=OneWay}" >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent">
                            <Image Width="30" Height="30" Source="/Inspections;component/Icons/pdf_btn.png" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
```

This is how I fixed the warning, where I moved the button below the first `StackPanel`:

```
        <Border VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource InspectionsCustomDataGridHeader}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Label Name="InspectionsDataGridTitle" Background="White" Content="{Binding InspectionsCollectionView.View.Count, ConverterParameter={x:Static resx:Resources.InspectionsDataGridTitle}, Converter={StaticResource DataGridHeaderCountConverter}}" Style="{DynamicResource InspectionsCustomDataGridHeaderLabel}" MouseDown="InspectionsDataGridTitle_MouseDown" />
                    <!-- more labels, etc... -->
                </StackPanel>
                <Button Grid.Column="2" Width="30" Height="30" Margin="0,0,10,0" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Command="{Binding CreatePDFCommand,Mode=OneWay}" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent">
                        <Image Width="30" Height="30" Source="/Inspections;component/Icons/pdf_btn.png" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
```

HTH