# Code structure for simple drawing apps when using MVVM / MVVMLight

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm currently using the `MVVM` pattern in one of my apps, to be more specific I'm using the `MVVMLight` framework. In one of the pages, I will have a screen where the user can input the `width` and `length` to draw rectangles, there is not much code logic so, I was thinking to put all of my code in the code-behind since most of what will be happening in this screen is UI related.

Does that make sense to use the code-behind in this case? If not, how would you structure the code to use the MVVM pattern, what would you put in the `ViewModel` in this case and what would you put in your code behind?

Here is the code without using MVVM.

### XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DrawingRectangles.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DrawingRectangles"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="531.798" Width="782.115">
    <Grid Name="MyGrid" Width="480" Height="240" Margin="27,23,267,174">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="59*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="421*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Canvas Name="MyCanvas" Background="#FFF1F0F0" Margin="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

        <Grid Margin="10,235,10,-92" Background="WhiteSmoke" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Button x:Name="drawButton" Content="Draw"  Click="drawButton_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="resetButton" Content="Reset" Click="resetButton_Click"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBoxPartWidth"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBoxPartLength"/>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### CODE-BEHIND:

```
namespace DrawingRectangles
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void drawButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            clearScreen();

            int xParts = 10;
            int yParts = 10;

            for (int i = 0; i < xParts; i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < yParts; j++) {
                    // Create a rectangle.
                    Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle();
                    myRectangle.Width = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxPartLength.Text);
                    myRectangle.Height = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxPartWidth.Text);
                    myRectangle.Margin = new Thickness((Convert.ToInt32(myRectangle.Width) + 1) * i, (Convert.ToInt32(myRectangle.Height) + 1) * j, 0, 0);
                    myRectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(170, 51, 51, 255));
                    MyCanvas.Children.Add(myRectangle);
                }
            }
        }

        private void resetButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyCanvas.Children.Clear();
        }

        private void clearScreen()
        {
            MyCanvas.Children.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

### UI

[image]

**EDIT:**
Second Image (reference only):
[image]

Comment: Generally speaking in MVVM button click = command and text fields = bindings to properties in view model. Your aim to have zero code behind and it seems it's possible for your task.

Comment: You can start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22324359/1997232) to see how to use canvas in mvvm.

Comment: Also take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40190793/1136211

Comment: Thank you both for the good info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Button` in the view should be bound to an `ICommand` property of the view model. The command will be executed when you click on the `Button`. Please refer to [this blog post](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/) for information about how to handle events in an MVVM application. In MvvmLight, the `ICommand` implementation is called `RelayCommand`.

You should also bind the `Text` properties of the `TextBoxes` to two source properties of the view model and the `Canvas` element in your view should be replaced with an `ItemsControl` that you bind to a collection of objects that are defined in the view model.

Please refer to the following sample code.

**Model:**

```
public class Model
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public Thickness Margin { get; set; }
    public Brush Fill { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Background="#FFF1F0F0" Margin="10" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" 
                       Height="{Binding Height}" 
                       Margin="{Binding Margin}"
                       Fill="{Binding Fill}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>

<Button Content="Draw" Command="{Binding DrawCommand}" />
<Button Content="Reset" Command="{Binding ResetCommand}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Width}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Height}"/>
```

**View Model**:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        DrawCommand = new RelayCommand(Draw);
        ResetCommand = new RelayCommand(Clear);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Model> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Model>();

    public RelayCommand DrawCommand { get; }
    public RelayCommand ResetCommand { get; }

    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }

    private void Draw()
    {
        Clear();

        int xParts = 10;
        int yParts = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < xParts; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < yParts; j++)
            {
                Model model = new Model();
                model.Width = Width;
                model.Height = Height;
                model.Margin = new Thickness((model.Width + 1) * i, (model.Height + 1) * j, 0, 0);
                model.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(170, 51, 51, 255));
                Items.Add(model);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Clear()
    {
        Items.Clear();
    }
}
```

In this example all application logic has been moved to the view model where it belongs. There is no logic left in the code-behind class of the view.

Also note that the view models creates instances of `Model` objects rather than creating `Rectangle` elements. It's generally considered be a bad practice to reference UI elements in a view model class. The `Rectangle` elements are created by the `ItemsControl`. See the `ItemTemplate` in the view.

Comment: you are creating multiple `new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(170, 51, 51, 255))` in a view model when SolidColorBrush is a UI element. it is a bad practice

Comment: have you linked your own blog? if yes, then it will be a good idea to disclose that.

Comment: Code correction, `Items.Add(myRectangle);` should be `Items.Add(model);`.

Comment: @fs_tigre: Fixed.

Comment: @mm8 - Quick question: This is more of a WPF question - what would be the best way to draw a second set of rectangles right after the first one. Something like the second image I uploaded (just now), note that the second set of rectangles are oriented differently than the first one. Do I need another `ObservableCollection` and another `ItemsControl` and just off-set the second `itemsControl` accordingly? Or can a second grid be added to the same `ItemsControl`? I know this is not related to the original question so, please feel free to ignore it.

Comment: @fs_tigre: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.