# Drawing Pie Chart

Tags: wpf, canvas, pie-chart, dependency-properties

After looking at several examples of creating piechart, I've made the following `UserControl` for that:

```
public partial class PieChart : UserControl
{
    #region DependencyProperties
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Radius", typeof(double), typeof(PieChart), new PropertyMetadata(0d));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SeriesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Series", typeof(List<PieSeries>), typeof(PieChart), new PropertyMetadata(null, Draw));

    public double Radius {
        get { return (double)GetValue(RadiusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RadiusProperty, value); }
    }

    public List<PieSeries> Series {
        get { return (List<PieSeries>)GetValue(SeriesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SeriesProperty, value); }
    }

    static void Draw(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = d as PieChart;
        control.AddPie(control.chartArea);
    }
    #endregion

    Brush[] colors = new Brush[] { Brushes.Gray, Brushes.Green, Brushes.Blue, Brushes.LightGray, Brushes.AntiqueWhite };
    double xCenter, yCenter;
    public PieChart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void AddPie(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.Width = 300; canvas.Height = 300;
        xCenter = canvas.Width / 2;
        yCenter = canvas.Height / 2;

        double sum, startAngle, sweepAngle;
        sum = Series.Sum(x => x.Value);
        startAngle = sweepAngle = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < Series.Count; i++)
        {
            var brush = colors[i];
            startAngle += sweepAngle;
            sweepAngle = 2 * Math.PI * Series[i].Value / sum;
            DrawSegments(canvas, brush, startAngle, startAngle + sweepAngle);
        }
    }

    void DrawSegments(Canvas canvas, Brush fillColor, double startAngle, double endAngle)
    {
        var line1 = new LineSegment() { Point = new Point(xCenter + Radius * Math.Cos(startAngle), yCenter + Radius * Math.Sin(startAngle)) };
        var line2 = new LineSegment() { Point = new Point(xCenter + Radius * Math.Cos(endAngle), yCenter + Radius * Math.Sin(endAngle)) };
        var arc = new ArcSegment()
        {
            SweepDirection = SweepDirection.Clockwise,
            Size = new Size(Radius, Radius),
            Point = new Point(xCenter + Radius * Math.Cos(endAngle), yCenter + Radius * Math.Sin(endAngle))
        };
        var figure = new PathFigure() { IsClosed = true, StartPoint = new Point(xCenter, yCenter), Segments = { line1, arc, line2 } };
        var geometry = new PathGeometry() { Figures = { figure } };
        var path = new Path() { Fill = fillColor, Data = geometry };
        canvas.Children.Add(path);
    }
}
```

with this in `xaml`:

```
<UserControl ...>
<Grid>
        <Canvas x:Name="chartArea" Margin="10"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

not sure whether this is the right way to do that BUT it works. The problem with this is in `AddPie` method. I've to set the `Width` and `Height` of the `Canvas`, otherwise nothing shows up in `MainWindow`. Here's how I've used it in `MainWindow`:

```
<Window>
    <Grid Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <local:PieChart Grid.Row="1"
                        Radius="100"
                        Series="{Binding Series}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and in the `constructor` of ViewModel, I've created the `Series`:

```
Series = new List<PieSeries>()
{
    new PieSeries("A", 30),
    new PieSeries("B", 20),
    new PieSeries("C", 10),
    new PieSeries("D", 15),
    new PieSeries("E", 25)
};
```

in `Draw` callback I always get `0` as `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` of that `Canvas`, named `chartArea`, so the Pie doesn't resize automatically when I resize the window!

How to fix that?

Is there any better way to Draw simple pie chart? In my case `List<PieSeries>` may have 1 item to 5 items in it.

### **EDIT**

With the approach suggested in the comments, it's much simpler! In my ViewModel, `VM`, I've these:

```
public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<ShapeData> Series { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ShapeData>();
    double[] array = { 30, 10, 15, 20, 25};
    Brush[] brushes = new Brush[] { Brushes.Gray, Brushes.Green, Brushes.Blue, Brushes.LightGray, Brushes.AntiqueWhite };
    double radius, xCenter, yCenter;

    public Command Resized { get; set; }
    public VM()
    {
        radius = 100;
        Resized = new Command(resized, (o) => true);
    }

    void resized(object obj)
    {
        var canvas = obj as Canvas;
        xCenter = canvas.ActualWidth / 2;
        yCenter = canvas.ActualHeight / 2;
        Series.Clear();
        DrawPie(array, brushes, radius);
    }

    void DrawPie(double[] values, Brush[] colors, double radius)
    {
        var sum = values.Sum();
        double startAngle, sweepAngle;
        startAngle = sweepAngle = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            startAngle += sweepAngle;
            sweepAngle = 2 * Math.PI * values[i] / sum;

            var line1 = new LineSegment() { Point = new Point(xCenter + radius * Math.Cos(startAngle), yCenter + radius * Math.Sin(startAngle)) };
            var line2 = new LineSegment() { Point = new Point(xCenter + radius * Math.Cos(startAngle + sweepAngle), yCenter + radius * Math.Sin(startAngle + sweepAngle)) };
            var arc = new ArcSegment()
            {
                SweepDirection = SweepDirection.Clockwise,
                Size = new Size(radius, radius),
                Point = new Point(xCenter + radius * Math.Cos(startAngle + sweepAngle), yCenter + radius * Math.Sin(startAngle + sweepAngle))
            };
            var figure = new PathFigure() { IsClosed = true, StartPoint = new Point(xCenter, yCenter), Segments = { line1, arc, line2 } };

            Series.Add(new ShapeData()
            {
                Geometry = new PathGeometry() { Figures = { figure } },
                Fill = colors[i],
                Stroke = Brushes.Red,
                StrokeThickness = 1
            });
        }
    }

    #region Notify Property Changed Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "") => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

    #endregion
}
```

and in `xaml`:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Series}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Path Data="{Binding Geometry}"
                    Fill="{Binding Fill}"
                    Stroke="{Binding Stroke}"
                    StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas x:Name="panel">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SizeChanged">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Resized}"
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=panel}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Resized}"
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=panel}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Canvas>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

with this in `xaml`, I get an warning on `<ItemsPanelTemplate>` tag

> No default constructor found for type
>   'System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerCollection'. You can use the
>   Arguments or FactoryMethod directives to construct this type.

Comment: Just a note, when `chartArea` is a member of PieChart, it seems pointless to pass it as argument to the AddPie method. Also, when you write `var control = d as PieChart` you should check the result for `null`. Better use an explicit cast like `var control = (PieChart)d;` because it would correctly give you an InvalidCastException (instead of an incorrect NullReferenceException) in case d is not a PieChart.

Comment: Besides that, the `Series` property is set before layout is performed. You control needs to redraw itself when its size changes.

Comment: @Clemens, that static `Draw` requires an instance.

Comment: AddPie is not a static method.

Comment: @Clemens, is it a must to have a `SizeChanged` handler?

Comment: I'd override OnRenderSizeChanged.

Comment: @Clemens, visual studio doesn't let me call non static method in a static method and it doesn't even let me pass `chartArea` as an argument even if I make `AddPie` static. It says object reference is required!

Comment: To me it seems also odd that you create and add those Paths manually. You already know how an ItemsControl works. Just use a Canvas as its ItemsPanel, and a Path in the ItemTemplate, which just has its Data property bound to a Geometry in the ItemsSource collection.

Comment: For your previous comment, you already call `control.AddPie`. No need to pass `control.chartArea` as argument. Inside AddPie, you can access the chartArea member because - as said - AddPie is not a static method.

Comment: @Clemens, that's where (ItemsControl) I got stuck! Since it looks odd asking a question without working example, I've posted this! I actually don't want to use this. I couldn't figure out how to do that with `ItemsControl`. Felt like I've to have one Converter to figure out the center point for `PathFigure`, two more for 2 `LineSegment` and one last for `ArcSegment`. Could you please provide an example with `ItemsControl`?

Comment: Start with an ItemsControl with a Canvas as ItemsPanel, that has its ItemsSource set to an `ObservableCollection<Geometry>` or an ObservableCollection of an item class with a Geometry property and a Brush property. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40190793/1136211

Comment: @Clemens, in that case I still have to compute `line1`, `line2`, `arc` and `figure` manually, like I did in this example, to add those in `Geometry` property of `ShapeData`, right?

Comment: Yes, of course. You may perhap translate the Canvas by half the width and height of your control, in order to have the Geometry coordinate system origin at (0,0)

Comment: @Clemens, yes that works BUT the Pie is in top left corner and 3 quarters of it got cut off! Is there a simple way to translate origin of canvas, or I've to have a value converter for that?

Comment: A RenderTransform or Margin should do.

Comment: @Clemens, I've used event triggers, see edit part.