# ToolTip in canvas elements

Tags: wpf, canvas, tooltip

I have programmed an application that draws elements in a canvas as described in
 [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43910360/wpf-adding-resource-element-to-canvas-and-binding-properties/43913638?noredirect=1#comment74879120_43913638)

I did it following the instructions of @grek40 and it works well.

Now I would like to add a tooltip to the elements drawn in the Canvas (only Tasks elements which are represented by a Border class). This is my code:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TaskItem}">
    <Border
    Background="#0074D9"
    BorderBrush="#001F3F"
    BorderThickness="2"
    Width="{Binding Width}"
    Height="{Binding Height}">
        <TextBlock
        Text="{Binding Id}"
        FontSize="20"
        Foreground="White"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Border.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip Background="#D5F0F0FF">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Reading Suggestion" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Charles Dickens" Margin="5"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ToolTip>
        </Border.ToolTip>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

But it doesn´t work. When I hover the Task elements (Border items) nothing happens. Any ideas what's wrong?

**UPDATE**

The Grid (x:Name="grid1") is contained in a custom control that handles zooming and padding. I implemented this following [this post in codeplex](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85603/A-WPF-custom-control-for-zooming-and-panning) (I followed the 'Simple Sample Code').

So my xaml looks like this:

```
<ScrollViewer
    x:Name="scroller"
    CanContentScroll="True"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    >

    <!--
    This is the control that handles zooming and panning.
    -->
    <ZoomAndPan:ZoomAndPanControl                
        x:Name="zoomAndPanControl"
        Background="LightGray"
        MouseDown="zoomAndPanControl_MouseDown"
        MouseUp="zoomAndPanControl_MouseUp"
        MouseMove="zoomAndPanControl_MouseMove"
        MouseWheel="zoomAndPanControl_MouseWheel"
        >

        <!--
        This Canvas is the content that is displayed by the ZoomAndPanControl.
        Width and Height determine the size of the content.
        -->
        <Grid x:Name="grid1">
            <ItemsControl x:Name="content"
                ItemsSource="{Binding TaskItems}"
                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource canvasTaskItemStyle}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas
                            Background="White"
                            Height="2000"
                            Width="2000"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
            <ItemsControl x:Name="contentLines"
                ItemsSource="{Binding TaskLineItems}">                    
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas
                            Background="Transparent"
                            Height="2000"
                            Width="2000"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
    </ZoomAndPan:ZoomAndPanControl>

</ScrollViewer>
```

Are maybe the commands of the ZoomAndPanControl interfering with the tooltip?

Comment: Are you sure? I just merged the tooltip into my example and it is showing without problem. Maybe some other part of your project is interfering?

Comment: That's possible because I have your code inside a custom control that handles zooming and paning. I have updated the post with information about it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overlaying two different itemcontrols inside the grid. The topmost control manages the lines and it has `Background="Transparent"`, so it will capture all mouse traffic and the underlying task item collection never receives the mouse over.

Solution 1 (hacky): swap the order or the Z-Index of items and lines.

Solution 2 (also hacky): remove the blocking background instead of making it transparent (`Background="{x:Null}"`)

Solution 3 (less hacky): Create a combined items collection that contains both, lines and taskitems in the data context and use a single canvas to present them.

One way of implementing solution 3 is combining the items in code behind, another is the use of `CompositeCollection`:

```
<ItemsControl ...>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding TaskItems}"/>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding TaskLineItems}"/>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
    ...
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: @chincheta73 no problem, see my edit for a suggestion how to create the combined collection without much efford.

Answer (score 0):

From the accepted answer in the linked post, it looks like you are using this template for items in an `ItemsControl`. The `ItemsControl` will put each item in a container with the style of the container defined by the `ItemContainerStyle` property.

Try putting the tooltip on the container instead of the item by adding it to the `ItemContainerStyle`. In the other post this is `canvasTaskItemStyle`.

```
<Style x:Key="canvasTaskItemStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter">
    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding CoordX}"/>
    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding CoordY}"/>
    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ToolTip Background="#D5F0F0FF">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Reading Suggestion" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Charles Dickens" Margin="5"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ToolTip>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Maybe, as suggested by @grek40another part of the project is interfering. I will update my question with more code