# How to bind ItemsControl (outside a grid) to the a grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

I have a viewmodel which contains an ObservableCollection of objects name MyLabel. These objects have 3 properties (content, rowNr, columnNr) which should be bound to the Content, Grid.Rowand Grid.Column attributes respectively.

The reason I defined ItemsControl is because it didnt work inside my grid, that is I couldnt bind rowNr and columnNr since the grids Grid.Column /Grid.Row properties kept overwriting my data.

How can I make this work so that my labels are inside of the grid?

```
<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyLabelList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding content}" Grid.Column="{Binding columnNr}" Grid.Row="{Binding rowNr}" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use a `Grid` as the `ItemsPanel` for the `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyLabelList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding columnNr}" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding rowNr}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding content}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: This will not work  because your label is not directly inside the `ItemsPanel`.

Comment: Will check it out. Looks interesting.

Comment: @Peter: It works with an ItemContainerStyle. You will of course have to define the RowDefinitions though.

Comment: Im a bit hesitant to implement things I dont understand but this is still ok for a mortal wpf user like me.

Comment: I think ill accept your answer. Testing a bit more : )

Comment: One last thing and ill accept your answer. Is binding column definitions too complex? If so should I just give the grid an x name and apply the definitions in code behind even if it violate mvvm principles?

Comment: Applying the column definitions in the code-behind does *not* violate the MVVM pattern. The pattern is about separation of concerns, not about eliminating *view* related code from the views.

Comment: I thought mv shouldnt know about view elements because id have to access my grid directly to give it some row / column definitions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the bindings to the `ItemContainer` programmaticly on `GetContainerForItemOverride()`

```
public class GridItemsControl : ItemsControl
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        FrameworkElement fwE = base.GetContainerForItemOverride() as FrameworkElement;
        fwE.SetBinding(Grid.ColumnProperty, "columnNr");
        fwE.SetBinding(Grid.RowProperty, "rowNr");

        return fwE;
    }
}
```

And in the View like this:

```
<custom:GridItemsControl>
    <custom:GridItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <!-- Add here -->
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!-- Add here -->
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </custom:GridItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</custom:GridItemsControl>
```

You could also implement an own grid that generates the wanted amount of rows and columns.

This trick is pretty legit.

**Additional Information**
Your `ItemTemplate` will not be directly added to your `ItemsPanel` (in your case a `Grid`) there is allways a `ContentPresenter` or something like this around, because you are using `DataTemplate`. So you have to go like this.

To make it more contrihensible you could imagine it like this:

```
                <Grid> <!-- This is the ItemsPanel -->
                    <ContentPresenter>
                        <!-- This needs the Binding on Grid.Row, but doesn't know shit without my solution -->
                        <!-- This is your ItemContainer that has the DataContext of your ViewModelItem -->
                        <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <!-- Here is your ItemTemplate -->
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Grid>
```

Comment: Peter is it just me or is this specific topic one of the more complicated aspects of xaml?

Comment: Your `ItemTemplate` will not be directly added to your `ItemsPanel` (in your case a `Grid`) there is allways a `ContentPresenter` or something like this around, because you are using `DataTemplate`. So you have to go like this.

Comment: Thanks, ill try this out and study it. Ill accept in a  moment

Comment: Does this violate MVVM in any way?

Comment: No it does not !

Comment: You could make it more generic if you want, but your `ViewModel` don't have to know about the structure of the `View`.

Comment: Could you explain the first section of code a bit more? and why you did custom: ? I could google it but since you already usedit in your answer it would be cool if you could explain how this works. Its not a must, just if you feel like it.

Comment: Added more info ;)

Comment: I googled custom: but could find anything.  What exactly is custom? Is it something like a user control? Thanks for the additional infos!

Comment: You could always use `ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle` to set the bindings on the `ContentPresenter` without the need to subclass `ItemsControl`.

Comment: There is an example of how to define an ItemContainerStyle for an ItemsControl in @Clemens answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22324359/add-n-rectangles-to-canvas-with-mvvm-in-wpf/22325266#22325266.

Answer (score 1):

A `Grid` and `ItemsControl` don't play that well together but you could refer to the following blog post:

**Using a Grid as the Panel for an ItemsControl:** http://blog.scottlogic.com/2010/11/15/using-a-grid-as-the-panel-for-an-itemscontrol.html

Another option may be to "manually" add the `<RowDefinition>` and `<ColumnDefinition>` elements to the Grid dynamically in the view.

Comment: *"don't play that well together"* - I am often using `Grid` with `ItemsControl` to contain multiple items which doesn't have layout relations (e.g. can override each other). In such case there are no problems with columns/row as you don't use them. Order of items is like z-order of controls in winforms.

Comment: Well, I guess it should be a Grid *with fixed columns and rows* doesn't play very well together with an ItemsControl then :)

Comment: Seems really complicated for such a simple task right? Refering to the article

Comment: That's what I mean by "don't play that well together". As mentioned you might be better of creating the <RowDefinition> and <ColumnDefinition> elements yourself in the code-behind of the view.

Comment: Or, if you know the actual number of rows up-front, you could refer to my first answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to subclass `ItemsControl` like @Peter suggested in his answer, you could simply use `ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle` to bind `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row` properties:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyLabelList}">
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <!-- Add here -->
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!-- Add here -->
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        </Grid>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding content}" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding rowNr}" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding columnNr}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

But, as others already mentioned, column and row definitions will not be added automatically and you'll either need to know it in design-time and add them statically, or you'll need to find some way to add them dynamically in run-time.

Comment: The definitions you mean? I was thinking of violating MVVM principles to achieve that. since I could give grid an x:Name and add new definitions when required.

Comment: @Asperger Yes, exactly.

Comment: Would you say that wouldnt hurt to violate the rules a little?

Comment: It won't hurt in terms of whether your code works or not, but it might hurt you and/or others in terms of code maintenance.