# How to properly set up a TwoWay Binding in wpf with Code

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have been trying to set up a two-way binding in wpf. There is a canvas that is populated with ContentControls, each one containing a filled rectangle. Through a thumb, each `ContentControl` can be made larger and therefore have a changed `width`.

These `ContentControls` have been generated by code and live within a class (`CanvasElement`), which is used for other calculations.

I'd like to set up a two way binding between the `ContentControl` Property Width and the public double variable Width within the `CanvasElement` class. When the `Thumb` is used to change the width of the `contentControl`, the `Width` of the `CanvasElement` is updated, but the other way it doesn't work.

#### Here is what I have so far:

```
 public class CanvasElement
{
    private double width;
    public double height;
    private Point location; // This is the upper left point of the rectangle
    public Brush color;
    public string UID;
    public ContentControl canvasElement;

    public CanvasElement(Point location, double width, double height, Brush color, string UID)
    {
        this.location = location;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.color = color;
        this.UID = UID;

        canvasElement = new ContentControl() { Width = this.width, Height = this.height, Uid = UID };
        Canvas.SetLeft(canvasElement, this.location.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(canvasElement, this.location.Y);

        canvasElement.Content = new Rectangle() {
            IsHitTestVisible = false,
            Fill = this.color,
            Stroke =Brushes.LightGray,
            StrokeThickness = 2,
            Margin =  new Thickness(0,5,0,5),
            RadiusX = 10,
            RadiusY = 10};
        addBinding();

    }

    private void addBinding()
    {
        Binding widthBinding = new Binding();
        widthBinding.Source = this;
        widthBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Width");
        widthBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        widthBinding.NotifyOnSourceUpdated = true;
        widthBinding.NotifyOnTargetUpdated = true;
        //widthBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(canvasElement, ContentControl.WidthProperty, widthBinding);

    }




    public double Width
    {
        get
        {
            return width;
        }
        set
        {
            if(width != value)
            {
                width = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

As well as:

```
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

I am thankful for every hint I can get!

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: A ContentControl member called `canvasElement` in a class called `CanvasElement` makes my brain hurt. Sorry.

Comment: I am very new to wpf, so I don't know if this is the right way to achieve this nor if I am using the right elements. My apologies.

Comment: It hasn't got to do with WPF. It's just that the names are confusing.

Comment: That said, you should consider using an ItemsControl with a Canvas as ItemsPanel and the Rectangle in its ItemTemplate. See this for a start: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22324359/1136211

Comment: I will look into that, thank you!

Comment: @Clemens: Thank you for this hint! After rewriting nearly the whole code the new setup with ItemsControl worked well and all TwoWay bindings are established.

Answer (score 0):

As Clemens pointed out in his comment the `ItemsControl` is the right way to do this. As I have different `UIElements` that are added to the canvas I needed to add an `ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector` as well as an `ItemsControlItemContainerStyleSelector`.

## XAML

```
<AdornerDecorator ClipToBounds="True">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CanvasElementList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Background="FloralWhite"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyleSelector>
            <local:CustomStyleSelector>
                <local:CustomStyleSelector.CanvasStyle_TL>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </Style>
                </local:CustomStyleSelector.CanvasStyle_TL>
                <local:CustomStyleSelector.CanvasStyle_TR>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Right" Value="{Binding Path=X, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </Style>
                </local:CustomStyleSelector.CanvasStyle_TR>
                <local:CustomStyleSelector.CanvasStyle_BL>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Bottom" Value="{Binding Path=Y, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </Style>
                </local:CustomStyleSelector.CanvasStyle_BL>
                <local:CustomStyleSelector.CanvasStyle_BR>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Right" Value="{Binding Path=X, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Bottom" Value="{Binding Path=Y, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </Style>
                </local:CustomStyleSelector.CanvasStyle_BR>
                <local:CustomStyleSelector.LineStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    </Style>
                </local:CustomStyleSelector.LineStyle>
            </local:CustomStyleSelector>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyleSelector>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
            <local:CustomTemplateSelectors>
                <local:CustomTemplateSelectors.LabelTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding Text}"
                                FontWeight="{Binding FontWeight}"
                                FontSize="{Binding FontSize}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </local:CustomTemplateSelectors.LabelTemplate>
                <local:CustomTemplateSelectors.LineTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Line X1="{Binding X1}"
                                    X2="{Binding X2}"
                                    Y1="{Binding Y1}"
                                    Y2="{Binding Y2}"
                                    Stroke="{Binding Stroke}"
                                    StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness}"
                                    StrokeDashArray="{Binding StrokeDashArray}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </local:CustomTemplateSelectors.LineTemplate>
                <local:CustomTemplateSelectors.CanvasElementTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl Width="{Binding Path=Width, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="{Binding Path=Height, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                    Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DesignerItemStyle}"
                                    MouseDoubleClick="ContentControl_MouseDoubleClick">
                            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Color}"
                                Stroke="LightGray"
                                StrokeThickness="2"
                                Margin="0,5,0,5"
                                RadiusX="10"
                                RadiusY="10"
                                IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </local:CustomTemplateSelectors.CanvasElementTemplate>

            </local:CustomTemplateSelectors>

        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
    </ItemsControl>
</AdornerDecorator>
```

## Code

In the corresponding .cs file there are these `ObservableCollections` and the `CompositeCollection`. The later is the element that binds to the ItemsControl. To add new elements you have to add elements to the `Observable Collections`

```
CanvasElementList4Canvas = new ObservableCollection<CanvasElement>();
LineList4Canvas = new ObservableCollection<CustomLine>();
LabelList4Canvas = new ObservableCollection<LabelTextBlock>();

CanvasElementList = new CompositeCollection();
CanvasElementList.Add(new CollectionContainer() { Collection = CanvasElementList4Canvas });
CanvasElementList.Add(new CollectionContainer() { Collection = LineList4Canvas });
CanvasElementList.Add(new CollectionContainer() { Collection = LabelList4Canvas });
```

To set up the binding the `CustomLine` Class is shown here. The CanvasElement and the LabelTextBlock class are set up in the same way.

### CustomLine

```
public class CustomLine : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _X1;
    private double _X2;
    private double _Y1;
    private double _Y2;
    private int _strokeThickness = 3;
    private Brush _stroke = Brushes.Black;
    private DoubleCollection _strokeDashArray = new DoubleCollection() {  1.0, 0.0  };

    public double X1 { get { return _X1; } set { if (_X1 != value) { _X1 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("X1"); } } }
    public double X2 { get { return _X2; } set { if (_X2 != value) { _X2 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("X2"); } } }
    public double Y1 { get { return _Y1; } set { if (_Y1 != value) { _Y1 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Y1"); } } }
    public double Y2 { get { return _Y2; } set { if (_Y2 != value) { _Y2 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Y2"); } } }
    public int StrokeThickness { get { return _strokeThickness; } set { if (_strokeThickness != value) { _strokeThickness = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("StrokeThickness"); } } }
    public Brush Stroke { get { return _stroke; } set { if (_stroke != value) { _stroke = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Stroke"); } } }
    public DoubleCollection StrokeDashArray { get { return _strokeDashArray; } set { if (_strokeDashArray != value) { _strokeDashArray = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("StrokeDashArray"); } } }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

and finally the custom selectors are needed to use the right template and the right style for within the canvas:

```
public class CustomTemplateSelectors : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate CanvasElementTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate LineTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate LabelTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is CanvasElement)
            return CanvasElementTemplate;
        else if (item is CustomLine)
            return LineTemplate;
        else if (item is LabelTextBlock)
            return LabelTemplate;
        else return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}

public class CustomStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    public Style CanvasStyle_TL { get; set; }
    public Style CanvasStyle_TR { get; set; }
    public Style CanvasStyle_BL { get; set; }
    public Style CanvasStyle_BR { get; set; }
    public Style LineStyle { get; set; }

    public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is CanvasElement)
            return CanvasStyle_TL;
        else if (item is CustomLine)
            return LineStyle;
        else if (item is LabelTextBlock)
        {
            var tempItem = item as LabelTextBlock;
            if (tempItem.Tag == "TL")
                return CanvasStyle_TL;
            else if (tempItem.Tag == "TR")
                return CanvasStyle_TR;
            else if (tempItem.Tag == "BL")
                return CanvasStyle_BL;
            else if (tempItem.Tag == "BR")
                return CanvasStyle_BR;
            else return base.SelectStyle(item, container);
        }
        else return base.SelectStyle(item, container);
    }
}
```