# Drawing Ellipse Line/PolyLine with a double

Tags: wpf, charts, shapes

I have been working with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59226916/automating-scaletransform-for-rectangles-in-bar-chart) example to draw bar graph. The bar part is done and it represents the volume/quantity in a transaction. It's an associated price in range 20 - 30. What I want now is to draw points to represent price associated with volumes and connect those points. Two changes I've made in EDIT part of the linked example (1) removed the `TextBlock` from the `DataTemplate` of `ItemsControl` and added an `Ellipse` instead and (2) edited the canvas to add price/volume axis label. Here's how it looks like now:

[image]

How to add those `Ellipse` in right position and connect those with `Line`/`PolyLine`?

**EDIT**

Here's what I've now in `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
            Height="135"
            ItemsSource="{Binding RectCollection}"
            Margin="50 0 50 0">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Canvas Width="20">
                <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                <Rectangle Width="18" 
                Margin="0 0 2 0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                Opacity=".5" Fill="LightGray">
                    <Rectangle.Height>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource VConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="ActualHeight"
                                    RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}"/>
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.HighestPoint"
                                    RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}"/>
                            <Binding Path="Volume"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Rectangle.Height>
                </Rectangle>

                <Line Stroke="DarkGreen" StrokeThickness="1"
                    X1="10" X2="30"
                    Y2="{Binding PreviousPrice, Converter={StaticResource PConverter}}"
                    Y1="{Binding CurrentPrice, Converter={StaticResource PConverter}}">
                    <Line.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Line">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PreviousPrice}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Line.Style>
                </Line>
                <Ellipse Fill="Red" Width="6" Height="6" Margin="-3" Canvas.Left="10"
                    Canvas.Top="{Binding CurrentPrice, Converter={StaticResource PConverter}}"/>
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}">
                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

oh! I forgot to add those ValueConverters, here're those:

```
public class VolumeConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var height = (double)values[0];
        var higest = (double)values[1];
        var value = (double)values[2];
        return value * height / higest;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class PriceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is double)) return null;
        var price = (double)value;
        var remainingHeight = 90;
        var priceRange = 30 - 20.0;
        return 45 + ((price - 20) * remainingHeight / priceRange);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and here's how it looks like:

[image]

As suggested by `@Clemens`, I've to have another `double?`, in case where `Insert(0, ... )` is used on `ObservableCollection` instead of `Add(...)` to add the last item in first place and removed the `AternationCount/Index` stuff.

Comment: As a note Ellipses are draw top/left-aligned. To draw them centered, add `Margin="-2.5"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example uses a vertically flipped Canvas to invert the y-axis order, so that it goes upwards. So `PConverter` should return positive y values.

Besides the Rectangle and Ellipse elements it draws a `Line` element from the previous data value to the current one by means of `RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}` in the value binding. It also uses a DataTrigger on the `AlternationIndex` to hide the first line.

```
<ItemsControl ... AlternationCount="2147483647">
...

<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Canvas Width="20">
            <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
            </Canvas.LayoutTransform>

            <Rectangle Fill="LightGray" Margin="1" Width="18"
                       Height="{Binding Value1, Converter={StaticResource PConverter}}"/>

            <Line Stroke="DarkGreen" StrokeThickness="3"
                  X1="-10" X2="10"
                  Y1="{Binding Price,
                       Converter={StaticResource PConverter},
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}"
                  Y2="{Binding Price,
                       Converter={StaticResource PConverter}}">
                <Line.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Line">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger
                                Binding="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex),
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                        AncestorType=ContentPresenter}}"
                                Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Line.Style>
            </Line>

            <Ellipse Fill="Red" Width="6" Height="6" Margin="-3" Canvas.Left="10"
                     Canvas.Top="{Binding Price, Converter={StaticResource PConverter}}"/>
        </Canvas>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

---

Since the value converter is now also called for a non-existing value (for `PreviousData` of the first item), you have to make sure that it checks if the passed value is actually a double:

```
public object Convert(
    object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (!(value is double)) return 0d;
    ...
}
```

Comment: There's a little issue with this, see edit part. It works fine If I use `Add` instead of `Insert`.

Comment: Looks like you haven't set the `Y1` Bindings correctly. All lines seem to have `Y1 = 0`.

Comment: No it's set. This is so because I've `Collection.Insert(0, ...)` instead of `Collection.Add(...)`

Comment: That should obviously not matter. The ItemsControl simply displays the items in the order of the collection, no matter how you have added elements.

Comment: I've tested it with `Add` and it works perfectly BUT it become like that if I use `Insert(0,...)`.

Comment: Maybe PreviousData is not refreshed when an item is inserted at the head of the collection. You may add a PreviousPrice member to you item class and bind that instead of the Price property of PreviousData.

Comment: You could also make the PreviousPrice property a nullable double (declared as `double?`) and make the DataTrigger operate directly on that property, with `Value="{x:Null}"`. Now you can drop the AternationCount/Index stuff.