# OnPropertyChanged not recognized by Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, attached-properties

I have several shapes where I want to change the opacity when I click on it, additionally I need to know in code which shapes were selected and I need to set the opacity from code behind.

My idea is to use a `Dictionary<int, bool>` with an index and if selected or not.
I know a `Dictionary` does not implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` or `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but I found an example of an observable dictionary, which triggers both events very well.

For each shape (rectangle) I set following binding:

```
<Rectangle Height="25" Stroke="Black" Margin="10" Fill="AliceBlue" StrokeThickness="3">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown" Handler="Rectangle_PreviewMouseDown"></EventSetter>
            <Setter Property="local:IndexProperty.SectorIndex" Value="1"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="local:SelectSectorProperty.SelectedSector" Value="{Binding SelectedRect, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

Within `Rectangle_PreviewMouseDown` I toggle the bool value of `ObservableDictionary<int, bool>` using SectorIndex.

Attached property looks like this:

```
public class SelectSectorProperty : DependencyObject
{
    public static ObservableDictionary<int, bool> GetSelectedSector(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ObservableDictionary<int, bool>)obj.GetValue(SelectedSectorProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSelectedSector(DependencyObject obj, ObservableDictionary<int, bool> value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SelectedSectorProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SectorList.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedSectorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedSector", typeof(ObservableDictionary<int, bool>),
            typeof(SelectSectorProperty), new PropertyMetadata(OnStatusChanged));

    private static void OnStatusChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnStatusChanged");
        if (obj is Rectangle element)
        {
            if (e.NewValue?.GetType() == typeof(ObservableDictionary<int, bool>))
            {
                var index = (int)obj.GetValue(IndexProperty.SectorIndexProperty);
                GetSelectedSector(obj).TryGetValue(index, out bool selected);
                if (selected)
                {
                    element.Opacity = 0.8;
                }
                else
                {
                    element.Opacity = 0.1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My ViewModel is this:

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        SelectedRect.PropertyChanged += SelectedSectors_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void SelectedSectors_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedRect));
    }

    private ObservableDictionary<int, bool> _SelectedRect = new ObservableDictionary<int, bool>() {
        { 1, false},
        { 2, false},
        { 3, false},
    };
    public ObservableDictionary<int, bool> SelectedRect
    {
        get { return _SelectedRect; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedRect = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedRect));
        }
    }
}
```

Once I update my `ObservableDictionary`, the `SelectedRect.PropertyChanged` event is triggered and also the `OnPropertyChanged` event, which is implemented in the `ViewModelBase` class, is called with the exact same parameters which would be called from the `SelectedRect` property itself.
But `OnStatusChanged` of my attached property is not triggerd, only if I change the reference of my `SelectedRect` property (e.g. setting to null and back to it).

This differs from my expectations, I would really like to know why, calling `OnPropertyChanged` with the correct parameters should be enough, but it seems there is more validation going on behind the scenes.

I guess updating the Binding explicitly is the way to go?

Comment: The PropertyChanged callback of a dependency property is only called when the value of the property has actually changed. Modifying a collection object is not a value change of a property that holds a reference to the collection object. Even if the view model fires a change notification like the PropertyChanged event, that doesn't mean the property value has actually changed. The notication is just silently ignored, so "*calling OnPropertyChanged with the correct parameters should be enough*" is a wrong expectation.

Comment: You should perhaps also think about having a view model (e.g. like [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22325266/1136211)) to manage you collection of rectangles. Them visualize them in a ListBox (instead of ItemsControl) and bind the ListBoxItem's IsSelected state to a property in the rectangle item class in the view model.

Comment: @Clemens thanks for clarification. This was just an isolated example, in reality the rectangles are polylines which create a track with different sectors inside a Canvas. Storing them in my ViewModel doesn't make sense, especially because it was a svg-file converted to a xaml-file.

Comment: It would however make perfect sense to store the selected/opacity state in some kind of Sector object, call it a view model or not.