ToolTip from a background object
I like to show some locations on a background image. For that I put a ListBox (with a Canvas as ItemsPanel) on top of an Image inside a Grid, something like that:
<Grid>
    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"
           ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding ImageToolTip}" />

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListSource}"
             Background="Transparent">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="...">
                <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10"
                         Fill="White"
                         ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>

That works like a charm.
Now I'd like to show information about the background image in the ToolTip of the image. But the ToolTip of the Image does never show up as long as there's the ListBox infront of it.
I already tried to set the Background of the ListBox to Transparent or to {x:Null}, I tried to set the Background of the Canvas to Transparent or to {x:Null}, but nothing helped so far.
In the future I might want to put another ListBox infront of the existing one to show other additional overlays, but I'm afraid as soon as the second ListBox is in place I can't see the ToolTips of the items of the first ListBox anymore, and I might not be able to click on the items of the first ListBox.
Any suggestions?

Why is it a ListBox and not an ItemControl? Do you need the ListBox's selection feature or the default ListBoxItem appearance?

An ItemsControl doesn't have a default ItemsContainer, and since I had to bind "Canvas.Left" and "Canvas.Top" for each item, I thought that might be better with a container object.

That is wrong. The item container type is ContentPresenter. See for example this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22325266/1136211

Even with Background="{x:Null}" the ListBox swallows all mouse events. You may verify that by attaching a MouseMove event handler. This is certainly due to a Border or ScrollViewer element in the ListBox's Template.
So you would have to modify the Template, e.g. like
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListSource}" Background="{x:Null}">
    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
            <ItemsPresenter/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>
    ...
</ListBox>

Or you just use an ItemsControl instead of a ListBox:
<Grid>
    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"
           ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding ImageToolTip}" />

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListSource}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="White"
                         ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>


ListBox inherits from ItemsControl. Can you please explain, why ItemsControl should work when ListBox doesn't work?
I try to change my code and see if it works.

ItemsControl works, but after changing from ListBox to ItemsControl I figured out that I might need the selected item after all. Thank you.

Then you would perhaps also set the ListBoxItems' Template in the ItemContainerStyle. It could be as simple as <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem"><ContentPresenter/></ControlTemplate>.
